# Cannot use South to migrate because models and DB differ

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south

I am in the process of switching from MySQL to Postgres because of all of the troubles I have been having with South and MySQL, but I can't even get this process done.

Right now my database is in a state of disarray. My main/models.py has additional fields that the database does not have columns for, so I am trying to migrate them using South, but I get errors.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
python2.7 manage.py dumpdata --indent=4 > dump.js
```

I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'kelp_goals.main_actionstep' doesn't exist")
```

I get the error because the actionstep exists as a model in mains/models.py, but the table doesn't actually exist in the database.

I do the following to try to create the actionstep column:

```
python2.7 manage.py schemamigration main --auto
python2.7 manage.py migrate main
```

Then, I get this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'main_goal' already exists")
```

How can I resolve these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest modifying your database by hand (or removing fields from your models), until you have models/database that are in harmony.. then you can start using South.

In any case, you should clean up the data/tables before you start transferring them to a different database engine.